# What is the best approach for generating forms in ASP.NET MVC using Razor and model Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been using ASP.NET MVC for a couple of weeks now and am absolutely in love with it.  I've been spending some time to figure out exactly how to generate form fields with a generic razor template,  using the model's meta data to generate the form fields.  It feels as if MVC leans more towards a view per model approach.  Below is what I have done so far, but it feels like it is a big hack.  I use ajax to submit data to WebApi controllers, but I've omitted that for clarity.

Sample Models

```
public class ClientDto
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationDto
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Organization Name", GroupName = "Company")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name", GroupName = "Company Admin")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name", GroupName = "Company Admin")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email", GroupName = "Company Admin")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1", ShortName = "Line 1", GroupName = "Address")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2", ShortName = "Line 2", GroupName = "Address")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country", GroupName = "Address")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City", GroupName = "Address")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Province", GroupName = "Address")]
    public string Province { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postal Code", GroupName = "Address")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Test Bool")]
    public bool TestBool { get; set; }
}
```

Razor Template

```
@model object
@{
    var modelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, Model.GetType());
    var properties = modelMetadata.Properties.Select(md => new WrappedProperty(md))
        .GroupBy(p => p.GroupName);   
}

<form class="form-horizontal" id="newClientForm" role="form">

    @foreach (var group in properties)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Key))
        {
            @:<fieldset>
            <legend>@group.Key</legend>
        }

        foreach (var property in group)
        {
            var md = property.Metadata;
            if (md.TemplateHint != "HiddenInput")
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="@md.PropertyName">@md.DisplayName</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.Editor(md.PropertyName)
                    </div>           
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <input class="form-control" id="@md.PropertyName" name="@md.PropertyName" type="hidden" />
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Key))
        {
            @:</fieldset>
        }
      }
</form>
```

In the Index.cshtml, I call Html.Partial to render the forms using instances of the Model Objects.

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Partial("_GenericFormTemplate", new OrganizationDto())
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Partial("_GenericFormTemplate", new ClientDto())
    </div>


</div>
```

Rendered Forms -
[Rendered Forms](http://i1353.photobucket.com/albums/q677/matt_smyth1/dynamicrazorformtest_zps0ee9e6c9.jpg)

Does MVC have a standard way for rendering from object metedata?

Comment: [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor.aspx), [EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel.aspx)

Comment: To add more info to that comment, check out Display and EditorTemplates. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Comment: I would still need to create a template for each model.  In the above, I'm using a single template which renders all input elements without having to know the properties of the model object before hand.